# How can I output from /usr/bin/time to a file at the right location within execution?

Tags: bash, shell, time

I'm writing a script to mass time a quicksort execution with different input files and flags, and output them in a formatted way in an external file. Here's part of the script so you can understand the context:

```
echo $file 
echo "Naive Pivot"
count=1
while [ $count -lt 4 ]
do
    echo "Run $count"
    count=$(($count+1))
    time ./quicksort -pn -so < $file
    echo
done
```

I've tried redirecting it normally (from stdout)

```
time ./quicksort -pn -so < $file > timing.txt
```

and attempted to redirect from stderr (though I may be doing that wrong).

```
time ./quicksort -pn -so < $file 2 >> timing.txt
```

I've also tried

```
/usr/bin/time -p -o timing.txt -a ./quicksort -pn -so < $file
```

And running the script with the standard stderr output setup like this

```
./testData.sh > timing.txt 2 > timing.txt
```

However, they both appends ALL timing data at the END of the file, instead of between the output of the echo commands I'd put before and after it. So whilst everything comes out in order in the command line, when I try to run my script directing output to a file, all the echo.

I've exhausted my personal knowledge and need help. How do I get the time command (time or /usr/bin/time) to properly output into my file at the location relative to their execution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey man, what's the contents of $file, I think I have a solution, but wanted to make sure I was aware of all variables before posting my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`time` is a bash builtin. `/usr/bin/time` is a simple command-line program. They require different treatment.

First, what I think you want to do is redirect both `stderr` and `stdout` to a file. In bash, you can do that with `&>file` (or `&>>file` if you want to append), or you can use the more general solution: `>file 2>&1`. (See "Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error" in `man bash`).

That will work fine with `/usr/bin/time`, which is an ordinary program which creates a subshell to run the program described by its arguments, and then outputs timing information to `stderr`.

But in the case of the bash builtin `time`, which is actually syntactically part of the command line, that won't work because the command line which is `time`d *includes* the redirects; the timing information is sent to the unredirected `stderr` of bash itself. To get what you want, you need to run the entire `time`d pipeline in a subshell:

```
(time ./quicksort -pn -so < $file) &> timing.txt
```

Comment: For me also works this  `setsid R -e "source('/home/some.R)" >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &`